# How can I Hide in Drupal 7 the bottom blocks in Add and Edit button for my content

Tags: entities

I made a new content type in Drupal 7 without problems, but now I want to hide the bottom block in the content Add and Edit fonctions
This block as some url's parameters, comments parameters ...I don(t want to show to the users or registered users

[image: my unwanted blocks]

I cant't find where and how I mask this blocks,
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have found the answer myself

If I use another login than admin the blocks are not shown,

Sorry

Answer (score 0):

U can use the module tab tamer for that